# Segmentation fault 11: C with MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi, openmpi

Implementing a parallel version of Game of Life using MPI, getting a segmentation fault (signal 11). New to MPI, and couldn't really get valgrind to tell me where exactly the error exists. Simplified my code and found that there exists a problem in the bold snippet.

Edit: marked the block of code where the problem exists

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if(argc!=5)
  printf("Incorrect number of arguments.\n");
  else{
  // program logic here
  int m, n, sum, pid, nprocs;
  char outfilename[16];
  FILE *outfile;
  FILE *infile;
  int r=atoi(argv[3]);
  int c=atoi(argv[4]);
  int gens=atoi(argv[2]);
  int **old, **new, *new1d, *old1d;
  int i,j;
  MPI_Status status;


  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&pid); //initializing MPI here

//prevented segmentation error by using atoi

//domain decomposition start

// problem arisis here
int seg=c/nprocs; //divide by width
int ghost=seg+1;
int row=r+1;
int tsize=ghost*row; //ghost cells

 old1d = malloc(tsize*sizeof(int));
   new1d = malloc(tsize*sizeof(int));
  old   = malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
  new   = malloc(r*sizeof(int*));

   for(i=0; i<ghost; i++){
    old[i] = &old1d[i*row];
    new[i] = &new1d[i*row];
  }
// problem ends 

if(pid==0){
        MPI_Send(&old[0][seg], c, MPI_INT, 1,  0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&old[0][ghost],c, MPI_INT, 1,  1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&old[0][1],   c, MPI_INT, 1,  2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&old[0][0],   c, MPI_INT, 1,  3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
else{
        MPI_Recv(&old[0][0],    c, MPI_INT, 0,  0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&old[0][1],    c, MPI_INT, 0,  1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&old[0][ghost],c, MPI_INT, 0,  2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Send(&old[0][seg], c, MPI_INT, 0,  3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}
infile=fopen(argv[1],"r");

if(infile==NULL){
    printf("Could not locate file.\n");
    exit(1);
}

  while(fscanf(infile,"%d %d",&m, &n)!=EOF){
    old[m][n]=1;
  }
  fclose(infile);
//repeat for number of generations
  for(n=0; n<gens; n++){

    for(i=1; i<=r; i++){
      for(j=1; j<=c; j++){

        sum =  old[i-1][j-1] + old[i-1][j] + old[i-1][j+1]
          + old[i][j-1] + old[i][j+1]
          + old[i+1][j-1] + old[i+1][j] + old[i+1][j+1];

        if(sum==2 || sum==3)
            new[i][j]=1;
        else
            new[i][j]=0;
      }
    }
   //copying old state into new state
    for(i=1; i<=r; i++){
      for(j=1; j<=c; j++){
        old[i][j] = new[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  //create new output file
  sprintf(outfilename,"output_%d",pid);
  outfile=fopen(outfilename,"w");
  for(i=1; i<=r; i++){
    for(j=1; j<=c; j++){
     if(new[i][j]==1){
     fprintf(outfile,"%d\t%d\n",i ,j);
     printf("%d %d",i,j);
     }
    }
  }

  fclose(outfile);
  MPI_Finalize();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: The input file life.data.1 has  X Y co-ordinates that denote live cells.

Comment: What did you do to simplify the application in order to get an idea of where the segmentation fault occurs? First simplify, then add more code to detect the exact fault location.

Comment: I implemented a parallel version of this without doing domain decomposition. So basically that's the one without MPI_send / MPI_receive and the part where I'm dividing the domain vertically.

Comment: Still, add more details of what you've tried and try to be more specific in your question. This is not a platform where you can dump code and have people solve your issue.

Comment: Update your question to indicate where the problem materializes. Please identify the block of code, or line even, where it occurs. Maybe someone will help.

Comment: What is argv[1] supposed to mean? I dont see it referenced anywhere. Hint: C uses zero offset. (  `for(i=1; i<=r; i++){` assumes one-offset, too, IMHO.

Comment: What command line arguments are you using when you run the program?

Comment: mpirun -n 4 main life.data.1 100 250 250

Comment: @Aditya with those arguments, I could not get the program to crash in the section you indicated was causing the problem. It did deadlock on the send/receive block, however, because processes with rank above 1 were waiting to send/receive messages to the root process.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out Clarissa. I have tried running it without the send/receive calls as well, gave me the same issue even then.

Comment: @Aditya The send/receive have non-crashing errors in them. I have the same question as Jeroen, which is: are you sure the error is where you think it is, and why do you think it's there?

Comment: Segmentation errors are generally due to pointers and memory allocation faults. I had a similar segmentation problem earlier in the non-domain-decomposed version which I resolved using the 'atoi' for command line to integer conversion and the program ran successfully. I ran this program by commenting the send/receive block but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Aditya yes, that is usually the cause of segfaults. But from my end, it looks like the error happens later in the program than where you think it does. In particular, you're accessing old[r] and new[r] after the file is read, and both such accesses are out of bounds. But without the input file, I can't tell you the first crash point, nor all of the errors.

Comment: Thanks Clarissa. Here's the link to the file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7h3i7loztqo755s/life.data.1?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wildplasser hinted at in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928256/segmentation-fault-11-c-with-mpi#comment53683591_32928256), the crash is stemming from the loop you have here (which is past where you indicated the problem is stemming from):

```
for(i=1; i<=r; i++){
  for(j=1; j<=c; j++){

    sum =  old[i-1][j-1] + old[i-1][j] + old[i-1][j+1]
      + old[i][j-1] + old[i][j+1] //This line causes a segfault
      + old[i+1][j-1] + old[i+1][j] + old[i+1][j+1]; //This line causes a segfault

    if(sum==2 || sum==3)
        new[i][j]=1; //This line causes a segfault
    else
        new[i][j]=0; //This line causes a segfault
  }
}
```

All of the lines indicated by a comment cause a segfault because of the index being accessed. Your loop gives `i` and `j` values `1` through `r` and `1` through `c` inclusive, respectively. However, it is only valid to access elements `0` through `r-1` in the `old` array and elements `0` through `r-1` in the `new` array. To fix this, we can change the outer loop to

```
for(i = 1; i < r-1; i++){
    //...code here...
}
```

Notably, this will not set every value in new. It's possible you meant to declare `old` to be size `row`, which is `r+1`. In that case, you could have the continuation condition be `i < r` in this loop. I'm not sure that's the case, though. This handles the errors arising from accessing elements in `old`.

However, there are still issues arising from the use of `old` and `old1d`. `old` has `r` (250) elements in it, but the only `ghost` (63) entries are intialized in this case. `old1d` never has any of the non-live values initialized, and the non-initialized values are sent with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`. You need to pick how large the `old` array is and make sure to initialize all of the values in it, and also pick how large the `old1d` array is and make sure all of its values are initialized. The same goes for `new` and `new1d`.

By changing the loops so that `old` and `new` are always accessed between indices `0` and `ghost-1` inclusive, and changing all of the loops so that each element of `old` and `new` (something like `old[i]` and `new[i]`) are always accessed between `0` and `r-1` inclusive, the program does not crash. This is done by keeping `i < ghost` (or `< ghost - 1` in the main loop) and keeping `j < r` (or, similarly, `< r -1`) for each loop. However, this almost certainly does not give the behavior you want. It looks like your current version of the loops are intended for a serial program, and ignore the parallelism you've tried to introduce by splitting the columns up into `seg`-sized pieces. The loops need to be completely re-designed so that their accesses use the parallelism in the program, and processes communicate so that adjacent cells across different processors have the appropriate communication. This requires a significant overhaul of the program.

There are two more issues that I want to point out:

1. The program hangs if you run it on more than 2 processes because the sends and receives are hard-coded to only communicate between process 0 and process 1. You need to make sure that processes 2 and above either don't try to send/receive, or are actually communicating when they send/receive.
2. When you compute `seg = c/nprocs`, the remainder of this division is being ignored. There are 250 columns, but seg becomes 250/4 = 62 (by integer division), and 62*4 = 248, which is less than the full number of columns. You need to make sure to deal with a non-clean division of columns into processes.

Comment: Solved the issue.Thank you so much Clarissa. The issue indeed was in the for loops. Changing the loops from i < r and j < c did the trick. Also, as you rightly pointed out, the for loops where the sum was being computed should have been from 0 to ghost as the domain had already been divided then. Also changed the condition to accommodate multiple (>2)  processes. So wish I could've up voted this answer but stackoverflow wouldn't let me do that (< rep) :( Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Also found that C doesn't automacatically allocate contiguous memory locations for multidimensional arrays. So I did this,      `     int *data = (int *)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
      int **array= (int **)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
      for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[cols*i]); `

Comment: No problem @Aditya. If you have gcc 4.8 or newer, I recommend using Address Sanitizer for debugging these kinds of issues, as it tells you exactly where the memory issues are. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html for an introduction; you don't need to use clang, although this documentation is for clang.